# Use DTO for transferring data

Tags: java, jaxb, dto

I am exploring about DTO. I read about using DTO in below URL:

http://www.servicedesignpatterns.com/requestandresponsemanagement/datatransferobject

As per this, DTO can have primitive data types like  integers, strings, etc. or other DTOs.

So, If I need to have collections like `List<Person>` in DTO then It will not transfer `List<Person>` or It will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTO are nothing but Java POJO classes without business logic.

If your DTO are keeping reference of Collection, it will behave just like any other object referred by DTO.

The DTO class will only hold reference of the Collection (Ex: ArrayList).
Any other class using the DTO will get the reference of the collection.
In other words, only reference to Objects (collections) will transfer not collections itself.

Comment: thanks for your valuable points.

Answer (score 1):

As per the article you have linked (emphasis my own):

> Data Transfer Objects (a.k.a. DTOs) are reusable classes that contain
>   **related data** and no business logic...

Thus, you *might* have scenarios where a particular DTO will have within it a collection of elements to which it is linked. Note though, that DTO's should be as lightweight as possible, thus, the collections could in turn contain ID's of other objects, possibly DTO's themselves which are related to the current DTO.

Comment: thanks for your valuable points.